# Create tf.keras.add Layer when Subclassing tf.keras.Model

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, tf.keras

**Objective**: build a neural net with skip connections, where the number of blocks is a parameter, and we subclass `tf.keras.Model`.

**Problem**: When subclassing `tf.keras.Model` we define the network layers in `__init__()` and specify the forward pass in `call()`. When a `tf.keras.layers.add` layer is defined in `__init__()` two arguments must be specified (the two tensors to be added). However, those tensors exist only within the scope of `call()`. Where and how does one provide the arguments to `tf.keras.layers.add()`?

Code is below. See lines ending with `# PROBLEM`. I tried creating instance variables to use as the arguments to `add()` (e.g. `internalTensor`, which is the internal "flow" tensor typically written as `x`) but no success.

```
class Network_very_simple(tf.keras.Model):

    def __init__(self, num_blocks):

        super(Network_very_simple, self).__init__()

        self.units_per_layer = 100
        self.num_blocks = num_blocks
        self.internalTensor = None

        self.block_output_tensors   = [None for _ in range(self.num_blocks)]
        self.block_shortcut_tensors = [None for _ in range(self.num_blocks)]

        # Individual layers
        self.flatten_layer = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()
        self.final_dense_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='linear')

        # Per-block layers
        self.block_dense_layers = []
        self.block_activations_0 = []
        self.block_activations_1 = []
        self.block_add_layers = []
        for block_num in range(num_blocks):
            self.block_dense_layers.append(tf.keras.layers.Dense(self.units_per_layer, activation=None))
            self.block_activations_0.append(tf.keras.layers.Activation('selu'))
            self.block_activations_1.append(tf.keras.layers.Activation('selu'))
            self.block_add_layers.append(tf.keras.layers.add([self.block_shortcut_tensors[block_num], self.internalTensor])) # PROBLEM

    def call(self, inputs):

        input_tensor = self.flatten_layer(inputs)

        for block_num in range(self.num_blocks):

            if block_num == 0:
                block_input_tensor = input_tensor
            else:
                block_input_tensor = self.block_output_tensors[block_num - 1]

            self.internalTensor = self.block_dense_layers[block_num](block_input_tensor)
            self.internalTensor = self.block_activations_0[block_num](self.internalTensor)

            if block_num > 0:  # Skip connection
                self.block_shortcut_tensors[block_num] = self.block_output_tensors[block_num - 1]
                self.internalTensor = self.block_add_layers[block_num]() # PROBLEM
                self.internalTensor = self.block_activations_1(self.internalTensor)

            self.block_output_tensors[block_num] = tf.keras.identity(self.internalTensor)

        self.internalTensor = self.final_dense_layer(self.block_output_tensors[-1])

        return(self.internalTensor)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two solutions:

1. Use `tf.keras.layers.Add`. Note the capital `A`. You can define this layer in `__init__` like any other layer, e.g. `add_layer = tf.keras.layers.Add()`, then use it on a list of two inputs in `call`, e.g. `added = add_layer([x1, x2])`.
2. There is really no need to use a layer to do addition. Simply do `added = x1 + x2` in the call. Only `Sequential` models need "everything" to be a layer.

Comment: so assuming `x1 = [1,2,3]` & `x2 = [1,1,1]` then `added = [2,3,4]`?